# Distribution of distinct candies among distinct bowls such that none is empty.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question: There are nine distinct pieces of candy. Jacob will throw these nine distinct pieces of candy into four distinct bowls. Each piece of candy is equally likely to land in any of the bowls and each piece of candy will end up in one of the bowls. What's the probability that none of the bowls are empty at the end of the throw?

OK, here's my attempt.

Using PIE:

1)All possible distributions of candies: $4^9$

2)Distributions in which atleast one bowl doesn't get a candy: $4 \cdot 3^9$

3)Distributions in which two bowls don't get candies: $ {4 \choose 2} \cdot 2^9$

4)Distribution in which three bowls don't get candies: $ {4 \choose 3} \cdot 1^9$

5)Distribution in which no bowl has a candy: $0$

Applying PIE, cases wherein each bowl has atleast one candy are:

$$ 4^9 -4 \cdot 3^9 + 6 \cdot 2^9 -4$$

Hence probability of this occurring is:

$$ \frac {4^9 -4 \cdot 3^9 + 6 \cdot 2^9 -4} {4^9} $$

Is this the answer gentlemen and ladies? If not, please provide a full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number the bowls with $1,2,3,4$ and let $B_{i}$ denote the event
that bowl $i$ stays empty.

To be found is: $$P\left(B_{1}^{\complement}\cap B_{2}^{\complement}\cap B_{3}^{\complement}\cap B_{4}^{\complement}\right)=1-P\left(B_{1}\cup B_{2}\cup B_{3}\cup B_{4}\right)$$

Here $P\left(B_{1}\cup B_{2}\cup B_{3}\cup B_{4}\right)$ can be found
by applying the [principle of inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability) and symmetry.

Give it a try.

Comment: Sir, please help a bit more... I can't proceed...

Comment: Can you find an expression of $P(B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3\cup B_4)$ on base of inclusion/exclusion? It starts with $=P(B_1)+P(B_2)+P(B_3)+P(B_4)-P(B_1\cap B_2)-\cdots$. Further we have $P(B_1)=P(B_2)=P(B_3)=P(B_4)$ so that the first $4$ terms can be replaced by $4P(B_1)$ (i.e. applying symmetry).

Comment: I've uploaded a solution, please check if it's correct.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank God and thank you sir!!! +1

Comment: As you ask me to: I will certainly thank Him ;-). Glad to help and nice to see that you could do the rest yourself.